# Finding the set of points where the function is not differentiable.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The exact problem :

> Let S be the set of all points in $\left (- \pi , \pi \right) $ at which the function , $f(x) = \textrm {min} \{\sin x, \cos x\}$ is non- differentiable. Then, S is a subset of which of the following?

1. $\{ \pi/4 , 0 , \pi/4 \}$
2. $\{ -3\pi/4 , -\pi/4 , 3\pi/4 , \pi/4\}$
3. $\{-\pi/2 , -\pi/4 , \pi/4 , \pi/2 \}$
4. $ \{-3\pi/4 , -\pi/2 , \pi/2 , 3\pi/4\}$.

To me the function $f(x) = \textrm{min} \{\sin x , \cos x \}$ seemed a little weird to check for differentiability by the [rigorous definition](https://www.mathopenref.com/calcdifferentiability.html) I tired to evaluate the function at various points and plotted it to look for any sharp edges. Here it is what I have done.

$$ f(0) = 0~~ , f(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0~~ , f(\frac{-\pi}{4}) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt 2}~~ , f(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}~~ , f(\frac{-\pi}{3}) = -\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}~~ , f(\frac{\pi}{3} ) = \frac{1}{2}$$.

[image]

The only sharp point I can see is the one at $x = \pi/3$. But what is the proper way to solve this question? And how to solve it?

**A harder question** :- Does this type of problems meant to be solved by a learner? I think that the person who has made this question is the only one who knows who to solve it in an exam with 30 such questions and in only one hour.

Comment: Note that $$\min\{x,y\}=\frac{|x+y|-|x-y|}{2}$$

Comment: @Qurultay Don't see how that's particularly helpful here.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The function will turn to a nicer one. Working with absolute value is more simple than that of $\min$.

Comment: You are right to look for sharp points. I think the question wanted you to observe that these points are exactly the points where $ \sin x = \cos x $.

Comment: @Qurultay I think with your hint I can use the rigourous definition of differentiability, ha?

Comment: @shortmanikos “I think the question wanted you to observe that these points are exactly the points where sin x = cos x” I’m not able to understand this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to find the points where $\cos(x)=\sin(x)$ i.e. the points where $f$ transitions from $\cos(x)$ to $\sin(x)$. This gives us $x=\pi/\mathbf 4$, not $\pi/3$ as you have, which does not appear in the answers.

You may want to graph $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ simultaneously to see this better.

Lastly, you should check the derivatives at $\pi/4$ to see that the function is not differentiable there.

Comment: *We wish to find the points where $\cos x = \sin x$* . Why we have to look for that? Please explain.

Comment: $\min$ will stop taking the value of one and start taking the value of the other.  It will _abruptly_ change direction and will not be differentiable at those points.

Comment: @adeshmishra Either $f(x)=\cos(x)$ or $f(x)=\sin(x)$. $f$ is differentiable over any open interval where it is strictly one of those. So the only case left is when it equals both. As I mention, you might want to graph $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ to get a better picture of what is happening.